# Jquery language change - change include with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, include

I have one question. I do not know if it is possible to do this way but maybe some one can help. Imagine you have 2 definitions php files, where languages are defined. I want to change those files with click on flag.

The aim of this is that i dont want to refresh page so i want to do it with jquery. Second thing is that my whole structure is that i only load files to div named contentwrapper. I was wondering about creating copy of each file in another language and with click i will empty every wrapper and load files with another languages.

I hope someone will understand what i want to do.

I wanted to load this definition file with 'flagclick' but this dont work. Its 100% that server will not reload definitions with jquery via load. Or maybe there is still that old definitions default file.

Can someone give me some hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See if this could help:

Bind a js function to your 'flagclick', which would send an Ajax call to the corresponding php file, like 'lang-en.php', 'lang-other.php'... to load all the context as Json object. And use the values from the Json data to replace all the text displayed.

Comment: Yes this will work . But u know i wanted to just load that file and the same definitions names are in both files. For example : in lang-en.php there is definition define('HOME','Home'); and in lang-sk.php there is also definition define('HOME','Domov'); So i want to use same <?=constant('HOME');?> in both languages. So if i could just load that file and my php will do the same without refresh, that would be great. But i think this is not possible :P